# Why isnt my jQuery/Javascript working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to learn some basic javascript and api usage.
Trying to get some weather information from Open Weather Map but none of the alert or console.log requests are being reported by the browser (Chrome).

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
    alert("this works first maybe");
    console.log("HEEEELLLLOOOOO");
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var i = 0;
            getJson();

            function getJson() {
                    console.log("getting data now");
                    $.getJSON("openweatherlink");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please **use a more explicit title**. There are 1.4m questions about JavaScript, luckily they do not all have a title of this kind

Comment: @user3547778 https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I thought it was a big vague when writing it. Ill learn.

Comment: This same code is working in mine machine. Probably it might be problem with your jquery import or project setup. I am using 1.12.5 version of jQuery.

Comment: @user3547778 Please consider marking one of the answers as a solution if any of those solved your problem. If you still have a problem with the current question, please let us know

Answer (score 11):

You can not use `src` in a `<script>` that contains code.

Use

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Your code
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  alert("this works first maybe");
  console.log("HEEEELLLLOOOOO");
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    getJson();

    function getJson() {
      console.log("getting data now");
      $.getJSON("openweatherlink");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Its always the simple things. Any advice for trying to troubleshoot these problems solo or are these type of hiccups un-avoidable? :)

Comment: Basic its learn by mistakes, No one in here can say they never made any code mistakes. I don't think there is any "direct" way to troubleshoot problems, except stay cool and take it 1 step at the time

Comment: @user3547778 Do you still have problems with this question?

Answer (score 0):

You code should be like below.

First script tag should contain jQuery import statement.

Second script tag  in which you can write jQuery/javascript code.

```
<script src="jquery-1.x-git.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    alert("this works first maybe");
    console.log("HEEEELLLLOOOOO");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var i = 0;
        getJson();

        function getJson() {
            console.log("getting data now");
            $.getJSON("openweatherlink");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("this works first maybe");
        console.log("HEEEELLLLOOOOO");
        var i = 0;
        getJson();
    });
    function getJson() {
         console.log("getting data now");
          $.getJSON("openweatherlink");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31672909)